# 誤字を見つける。phpのエラーが分からない。

Tags: php, html

APIを利用して誤字を見つけるものを作りたいのですが、行き詰ってしまったので質問させてもらいます。
とりあえず現在はエラーがでないようにしたいです。

**表示されるメッセージ:**

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\卒研\sotuken.php on line 24
```

**現状のコード:**

```
<?php
$post_flag = false;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
  $post_flag = true;
  $url = "https://api.a3rt.recruit-tech.co.jp/proofreading/v2/typo";
  $apikey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  $sentence = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", " ", "　"), "", @$_POST['text']); //入力文章
  $sensitivity = @$_POST['sensitivity']; //チェック感度（low、medium、high）
  $postdata = array(
    "apikey" => $apikey,
    "sentence" => $sentence,
    "sensitivity" => $sensitivity
  );
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);  
  $curl = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $results = json_decode($curl, true);

  $alerts = @$results["alerts"] ?: '';
//クロスサイトスクリプティング(XSS)の脆弱性を防止
  $checked_sentence = htmlspecialchars($results['checkedSentence'], ENT_QUOTES);
  $checked_sentence = str_replace(array('&lt;&lt;'), '<span class="error">', $checked_sentence);
  $checked_sentence = str_replace(array('&g t;&gt;'), '</span>', $checked_sentence);

  function get_alert_text ($score){
    $text = '';
    if ($score > 0.7) {
      $text = "誤字の可能性: 大";
    }
    elseif ($score > 0.3) {
      $text = "誤字の可能性: 中";
    }
    else {
      $text = "誤字の可能性: 小";
    }
    return $text;
  }

  $status_code = array(
    "0" => "正常応答（指摘なし）",
    "1" => "正常応答（指摘あり）",
    "1000" => "APIキー未指定",
    "1001" => "APIキーが見つからない",
    "1002" => "退会済み",
    "1003" => "アカウント未承認",
    "1010" => "サーバが見つからない",
    "1011" => "サーバ設定エラー",
    "1030" => "アクセス拒否",
    "1400" => "リクエストパラメータが不正",
    "1400" => "リクエストパラメータが不正 (sentenceがUTF-8でない）",
    "1404" => "指定したオブジェクト見つからない",
    "1405" => "メソッドが正しくない",
    "1413" => "リクエストパラメータの値が長すぎる",
    "1500" => "サーバ処理中に想定外のエラーが発生",
  );
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="sotuken.php" method="post">
    <p>入力エリア：<br>
    <input type="text" name="text"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="送信"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 表示されているのはあくまでワーニング (警告) であり、エラーとは意味合いが異なります。このメッセージが出ることでどのような問題があるのかを、もう少し具体的に説明してもらうと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

は、配列でない変数を配列としてアクセスした時に警告が出ます。*（「null」や「数値型」の変数など）*
$resultsに配列を入れている　**json_decode**は　nullを渡されると、nullを返します。
したがって curlの通信結果が null を返していると思います。

追伸、 @を付けてWarning表示を抑制せずに原因を１つ１つ追求した方が良いと思います。